# Remove rows that have a duplicate in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2), rep("D", 1))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2,5)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

Based on `df$a`, i would like to return only the values that do not have a duplicate (those rows that have a single occurence of `df$a`), in this example it would be `1 D 5`

I have tried `duplicate()`, `!duplicate()` and `unique()` but none outputs what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option

```
df[!(df$a %in% df$a[duplicated(df$a)]),]

  a b
9 D 5
```

Comment: Nice+1, for sake of readability maybe `df[!with(df, a %in% a[duplicated(a)]), ]`.

Answer (score 3):

Cleanest way with **`dplyr`**:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(a) %>%
   filter(n() == 1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   a [1]
  a         b
  <chr> <dbl>
1 D         5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, tmp:= .N, by = a][tmp == 1, -"tmp"]
   a b
1: D 5
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Base R` ,

```
x <- table(df[,1])

df[rep(x<2,x),]
```

gives,

```
#   a b
# 9 D 5
```